# spring MVC Controller and JSP

Tags: spring

```
<body>
 <form command="prod" action="home">
 <c:out value="${prod.pid}"/>

 <input type="submit" value="home">
 </form>

</body>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/viewprod")
public ModelAndView viewprod(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute Product prod) {
    int pid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));     
    Product p=ps.getProdByID(pid);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("viewprod") ;
    // Product p=ps.getProdByID(pid);
    mav.addObject(" prod", p);  
    return mav;
}
```

How to display the prod value in viewprod.jsp and also pass that as a parameter to another jsp

Comment: You should remove the space in `" prod"` at least.